# not able to load mobilenet v3 in tfjs-node

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, neural-network, tensorflow.js, image-classification

I've been trying to train a dataset using mobilenet v3 transfer learning and tensorflow.js node but I can't add the model for some reason. I'm always getting an error. What am I doing wrong in the code?

The error I get is

```
/Users/Documents/mah-project/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-layers/dist/tf-layers.node.js:25853
            if (layer.inboundNodes.length === 0) {
                                   ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')
    at Sequential.add (/Users/Documents/mah-project/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-layers/dist/tf-layers.node.js:25853:36)
```

The code

```
const baseModel = await tf.loadGraphModel(
            'https://tfhub.dev/google/tfjs-model/imagenet/mobilenet_v3_large_075_224/feature_vector/5/default/1',
            { fromTFHub: true });

        const model = tf.sequential();
        model.add(baseModel);

        model.add(tf.layers.flatten());
        model.add(tf.layers.dense({ units: 128, activation: 'relu' }));
        model.add(tf.layers.dense({ units: 2, activation: 'softmax' }));

        model.compile({
            optimizer: 'adam',
            loss: 'sparseCategoricalCrossentropy',
            metrics: ['accuracy'],
        });

        prepareDataset(datasetPath, imageDimensions).then(async (data) => {

            model.fit(data.xTrain, data.yTrain, {
                epochs: 10,
                validationData: [data.xTest, data.yTest],
            }).then(async (history) => {
               // other code
            });
        })
    }
```